# AngularJS Checkbox not working

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a class called Case that contains a list of executionSteps. Each executionStep has a boolean property called enabled. I am trying to set in on the HTML side but it never gets updated on the JS side.
HTML side

```
<td>
<input type="checkbox" 
  ng-checked="acase.executionSteps[0].enabled"
  ng-model="aa" ng-change="updateCaseExecutionStep('{{study.id}}','{{acase.id}}','{{acase.executionSteps[0].id}}','{{acase.executionSteps[0]}}')"/>
</td>`
```

On the controller side I have the function
    updateCaseExecutionStep 
defined as shown below

```
$scope.updateCaseExecutionStep = function(studyId,caseId,executionStepId,executionStep){  
    ...
    ...
}
```

Problem is when I update my checkbox or even manually update the enabled property of the executionStep

```
$scope.updateCaseExecutionStep = function(studyId,caseId,executionStepId,executionStep){  
    executionStep.enabled = true;
    ...
}
```

I don't see any change. The enabled property of executionStep passed in the JS does not change. Please help.

Do I have to modify somehow on the The HTML side ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or a plunker

Comment: I don't think you need all those double brackets, this would work fine: `ng-change="updateCaseExecutionStep(study.id,acase.id,acase.executionSteps[0].id,acase.executionSteps[0])"`

Comment: That seems to work, how do you pass in the true/false value from the HTML to the JS. Is there a way to pass in the true/value in the function call. For instance in my updateCaseExecutionStep(), how do I pass the state of if it has been clicked(true) or not(false)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are trying to force too complex solution. To start with, you do not need `ng-checked` nor `ng-change` when you are using `ng-model`.

Let's say you have the following controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.case = { 
    caseId: 0,
    steps: [
      { id: 1, name: 'First step', enabled: true }, 
      { id: 2, name: 'Second step', enabled: false },
      { id: 2, name: 'Third step', enabled: false }]
    };
});
```

And related HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="step in case.steps">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="step.enabled">&nbsp;{{ step.name }}
</div>
```

That's all it takes!

Example Plunk here http://plnkr.co/edit/QjD91l

**Edit:**

If you need to do some processing based on selection, then yes, you could add `ng-change` to `input` control. Then HTML becomes

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="step.enabled" ng-change="stateChanged(step)">&nbsp;{{ step.name }}
```

And in controller

```
$scope.stateChanged = function(step){
  console.log('Changed step id:' + step.id + ' enabled state to ' + step.enabled;   
};
```

Comment: How would I know which Checkbox has been clicked on the JS side

Comment: Edited the answer and plunker.

Comment: Thanks Mikko, the first answer itself worked. I appreciate your help. Its very kind of you.

Answer (score 4):

I had to abandon ng-model for my checkbox as it was not picking up the initial value that was set in the model (in response to a service call).  All of the other input controls were responding correctly to the model (and, interestingly, were correctly enabled/disabled based on the value backing the checkbox).

Instead, I used the 'checked' attibute and ng-click, as so:

```
<input type="text" ng-disabled="!myModel.isFruit" ng-model="myModel.seedCount">

<input type="checkbox" checked="{{myModel.isFruit}}" ng-click="onFruitClicked()"> Is Fruit
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.myModel = {
    isFruit : myServices.getIsFruit(),
    seedCount : myServices.getSeedCount()
};

$scope.onFruitClicked = function() {
    // toggle the value
    $scope.myModel.isFruit = !$scope.myModel.isFruit;
    // save the new value
    myServices.setIsFruit($scope.myModel.isFruit);
};
```

Comment: I wish I'd read this two days ago! I'm doing the same as you.