# AngularJS Checkbox retain check value when the page reloads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a search screen with a checkbox, and want to retain the checkbox selection when the user navigates away and comes back to the screen. 
Using the session storage, i am able to retain the value in the model, but the checkbox checked does not display correct based on the model value.
When I search online, it looks like i cannot use ng-model and ng-checked together. But I don't want to use jquery either. 
Is it possible to do this with just Angular? Thanks in Advance.

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="SearchController as vm" data-ng-init="vm.init()">
<form ng-submit="vm.Search()">
<input type="checkbox" id="chkActive" name="chkActive" value="Active"  ng-model="vm.searchInput.active" ng-checked="vm.searchInput.active"  /> <span>Show Active Records</span>
 <button id="searchBtn" type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Angular Controller Code:

```
vm.searchInput = { active: true};

vm.init = function () {
if ($window.sessionStorage.getItem("Search_Active")) {
    vm.searchInput.active = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('Search_Active');   }
}

vm.Search = function () {
    $window.sessionStorage.setItem('Search_Active', vm.searchInput.active);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000896/angularjs-checkbox-not-working/25002782#25002782

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it, but I'm sure the first line should read:

```
vm.searchInput = { active: true};
```

Comment: My bad, I have the same in my actual code vm.searchInput = { active: true}; , but this is not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the model value is there, you want to bind to it, and you know it's good then why would you need both `checked` and `model`? Binding the value to the input is enough. As you can see below, using both is problematic.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('c', c);

function c() {
  var self = this;
  self.checked = true;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app "app" ng-controller="c as ctrl">
  <div>
    <label>Checked</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checked" />
    <div>
      <span>Checked: {{ctrl.checked}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Checked Trouble</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.checked" ng-checked="!ctrl.checked" />
    <div>
      <span>Checked: {{ctrl.checked}}, !Checked: {{!ctrl.checked}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <label>Checked Double Trouble</label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="!ctrl.checked" ng-model="ctrl.checked" />
    <div>
      <span>Checked: {{ctrl.checked}}, !Checked: {{!ctrl.checked}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need both model and checked, because need to show on the screen what is checked last time user was on the screen.

Comment: @Reddy, but they're both using the same value. If it's a loading issue then add an `ng-if=vm.loaded` or similar to keep it from rendering until you have the stored value.